# In vue, how do I check if any parent component has subscribed for an event which child is emitting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which is sometimes being used as a child of a parent and sometimes it does not have any parent.

This component emits a particular event which either being caught by the parent ( if subscribed) or I would like to handle it by this component itself.

So at run time, How do I programmatically check

```
if (someone is listening to the event){
    let them catch and handle it
}else {
    let's handle it by our own
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This allows you to check listeners passed to a component:

```
this.$listeners;
```

It returns the parent scope event listeners. See [the doc here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners).

In particular for your use-case:

```
// To check whether the "myEvent" event is listened to
if (this.$listeners.myEvent){
  // let them catch and handle it
} else {
  // let's handle it by our own
}
```

Comment: 'This seems like a questionable design' I was looking to do just this for a component of mine. The child component displays an amount field and parents react to changed of this field. Now we wanted to have this same component not display the plus and minus button if the parent was using the component as read-only by not subscribing to the event... Sounds not so bad of a design to me.

Comment: I agree. I guess my imagination was running low on that day :) I'll remove that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a boolean prop from your parent.

In Parent Component :

```html
<Child :isParent='true'></Child>
```

In Child Component :

```js
props : {
  isParent : Boolean
},

methods : {
  actionEvent : function(){
    if(this.isParent){
      // Emit event
    }
    else{
      // Take care over here.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. But can we do that without polluting the prop space for that? @vaibhav

Comment: Other option is you can refer to bernie's answer, theoretically it should work.